# PDOException SQLSTATE[IMSSP] there is a statement with pending results

Tags: php, doctrine

Technologies used:

DOCTRINE 2.4.*/
PHP 5.3.0/
SQL SERVER 2000/
XAMPP 1.7.2

The SQL Server 2000 is installed on Windows 2003 Server.

This web application on a computer with XAMMP and windows 7 32bit.

To connect to the database sql server 2000 I need the driver sqlsrv2.0 and install windows 2008 native client 32 bits.
For this, I add in the file php.ini:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll
```

Now, when I run phpinfo() shows me sqlsrv pdo drivers.

When I query the database in an error occurs.
The connection to the database is ok. When I use the method find () or findAll () it works.

citas.php:

```
<?php

require_once "../doctrine/bootstrap.php";
$query = $entityManager->createQuery('SELECT c FROM Cita c WHERE (c.CodigoCita>?1)');
$query->setParameter(1,100);
$citas = $query->getResult();
echo count($citas);
```

Error:

```
br />

    <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: 
    The connection cannot process this operation because there is a statement with pending results.  
    To make the connection available for other queries, either fetch all results or cancel or free the statement.  
    For more information, see the product documentation about the MultipleActiveResultSets connection option.' 
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\HistoriaRedonda\doctrine\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection.php:694
    Stack 
    trace:
    #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\HistoriaRedonda\doctrine\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection.php(694): PDOStatement-&gt;execute()

    #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\HistoriaRedonda\doctrine\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister.php(748): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection-&gt;executeQuery('SELECT t0.Codig...', Array, Array)

    #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\HistoriaRedonda\doctrine\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister.php(829): Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister-&gt;load(Array, NULL, Array)

    #3 C:\xam in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\HistoriaRedonda\doctrine\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException.php</b> on line <b>91</b><br />
```

Connection.php:694Stack:

```
public function executeQuery($query, array $params = array(), $types = array(), QueryCacheProfile $qcp = null)
    {
        if ($qcp !== null) {
            return $this->executeCacheQuery($query, $params, $types, $qcp);
        }

        $this->connect();

        $logger = $this->_config->getSQLLogger();
        if ($logger) {
            $logger->startQuery($query, $params, $types);
        }

        try {
            if ($params) {
                list($query, $params, $types) = SQLParserUtils::expandListParameters($query, $params, $types);

                $stmt = $this->_conn->prepare($query);
                if ($types) {
                    $this->_bindTypedValues($stmt, $params, $types);
line 694                   $stmt->execute();


                } else {
                    $stmt->execute($params);

                }

            } else {
                $stmt = $this->_conn->query($query);
            }

        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            throw DBALException::driverExceptionDuringQuery($ex, $query, $this->resolveParams($params, $types));
        }

        $stmt->setFetchMode($this->defaultFetchMode);

        if ($logger) {
            $logger->stopQuery();
        }

        return $stmt;

    }
```

bootstrap.php:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';


$isDevMode = true;
$conn = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_sqlsrv',
    'host'     => '192.168.1.6',
    'dbname'   => 'MedicosCopia272015',
    'user'     => 'XXX',
    'password' => 'XXXXXXXXXX',
    'MultipleActiveResultSets' => false
);

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src"), $isDevMode);
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all try and restart the apache and SQL server.
2. Check if PDO is correctly configured for SQL queries.
3. One or more PDO process is either paused for lifetime Or is improperly closed. Please find and kill all the PDO process. Use `ps aux | grep "someprocess"` to find the running PDO processes and `pkill -p processid` to kill each running PDO process.

Comment: Sorry the delay in replying
Thanks for answering

I do not know how the process is called.
The operating system is Windows 7. 
Can you help me?

I have added more information about the problem in consultation.
Thank you